# Error: Cannot read property 'data' en Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Soy nueva con Angular, y más aún con Angular Material, por lo que la pregunta puede ser un poco confusa.

He generado un componente tabla con el comando:

```
ng generate @angular/material:table --nombre
```

Esto ha generado, a parte del template, el css, el spec y el archivo `.ts`, un archivo adicional terminado en **datasource**, que es donde se encuentran los datos que se muestran en la tabla:

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

export interface TabpruebaItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
const EXAMPLE_DATA: TabpruebaItem[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
];
export class TabpruebaDataSource extends DataSource<TabpruebaItem> {
  data: TabpruebaItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<TabpruebaItem[]> {
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    this.paginator.length = this.data.length;

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  disconnect() {}

  private getPagedData(data: TabpruebaItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  private getSortedData(data: TabpruebaItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

El archivo .ts que se genera, inicializa estos datos en la función ngAfterViewInit():

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { TabpruebaDataSource } from './tabprueba-datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabprueba',
  templateUrl: './tabprueba.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabprueba.component.css']
})
export class TabpruebaComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: TabpruebaDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource = new TabpruebaDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
  }
}
```

Si ejecuto la aplicación tal cual, obtengo un error en la consola que dice:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

El error está en el HTML:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource.data.length" <!-- error -->
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Esto me dice que `dataSource` no está definido, sin embargo yo estoy inicializando esos datos en `ngAfterViewInit()`. Si en vez de inicializar los datos ahí, los inicializo en `ngOnInit()`, la aplicación funciona correctamente y se renderizan todos los datos. Mi pregunta es, **¿por qué pasa esto?** Y si esto no es correcto, ¿por qué angular material lo genera así? ¿Tengo que añadir algo dentro del método? Con los demás componentes no he tenido que modificar nada para que funcionaran correctamente.

Según he podido leer, `ngOnInit` se ejecuta una sola vez después de que el componente se haya creado, y `ngAfterViewInit` hace lo mismo pero una vez que ha terminado de renderizar la plantilla `HTML`.

Comment: Tu mismo lo has dicho. el ngOnInit se invoca antes de que el html se haya cargado. Por lo tanto, tiene el tiempo de inicializar la variable datasource. En cambio el ngAfterViewInit() se invoca despues de cargar el html. Por lo tanto el html aun no cuenta con la variable datasource

Comment: Aquí tienes un [enlace](https://www.pensemosweb.com/angular-hooks-del-ciclo-de-vida-de-un-componente/) donde lo explica extensamente.

Comment: @David_helo eso lo entiendo, pero por qué angular material lo genera así? Para las que empezamos, es bastante confuso. Se supone que los datos se tienen que inicializar en el ngAfterViewInit() y en el ngOnInit() tiene que haber un paso previo, o ya hago bien inicializando el dataSource en ngOnInit()?